# Teaching in Germany with an MFA?

Tags: masters, teaching, germany

I have a BS in computer science and an MFA in Fine Art.

I am planning a move to Germany (and am in the process of learning German).  Is it possible to find work teaching at art colleges in Germany with an MFA?  I currently teach computer science and design/media at a college here in the US.

(I'm assuming I need to be fluent in German, but that might not always be the case because of the increase in international programs?)

If someone could point me to a good informational site that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: You have a Master of Fine Arts in Fine Art?

Comment: Forget it. In German art schools being an actual well known artist can get you around the otherwise necessary doctorate.

Comment: Yes, I have an MFA in Fine Art which is considered terminal in the US.

Comment: I'm just poking fun at the repetition. The "FA" in "MFA" already means "Fine Arts". It's like saying "ATM machine" or "PIN number".

Comment: Except that these days you can get an MFA in music, design, or dozens of other fields as well.  It's just come to mean a terminal degree in the field as opposed to an MA in the arts which is not considered terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Lectures in Germany are normally given by professors, who by law need to have a PhD (and sometimes a *Habilitation*). There may be some wiggle room for adjuncts, but normally *Wissenschaftliche Mitarbeiter*—the research staff working under the professor—assist with teaching discussion or recitation sections as well as grading, but generally do not give lectures except in the case of absences by the professor.

Part of this is because the funding for academic groups is based on the number of exams graded by a given chair. So faculty will be reluctant to give away lectures, and thus lose out on the “credit” associated with the teaching.

There might be a room for an exception if there is a vacancy due to retirement or poaching. Otherwise, it’s probably hard to get a university lecture with just a master’s degree.

Comment: There are also pure teaching positions (Lehrkraft für besondere Aufgaben), but they are extremely rare – in my fields (maths and physics), there is roughly one vacancy per month in the entirety of Germany.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: But are those master’s eligible?

Comment: Some are announced as such. But then, given the rarity of this positions, you might need to be the perfect candidate anyway …

Comment: @Wrzlprmft That's 12 jobs a year. It's rare but not "incredibly rare" if you compare it to the number of professors hired each year, is it?

Comment: The total number of open professorships in Germany is much larger than 12. When I entered Germany I thought (and still think) that the German system is weird: you only have temporary positions (PhD students and postdocs (wissenschaftliche mitarbeiter)) or professors, who have a permanent contract. There is virtually nothing in between. I always think of German universities as an army consisting only of generals. In some federal states lecuturers (Hochschuldozent) exist, but they are really rare. I have such a position, and the people have no idea how to fit me into the organization.

Comment: *It's rare but not "incredibly rare" if you compare it to the number of professors hired each year, is it?* – To do a rough calculation: fifty thousand professors in Germany, staying in the job for thirty years → ≈ 1600 positions per year. That’s for all fields, but it excludes people with *Habilitation* who are not full professors (many of which would be a professor in anglophone academia). Also keep in mind that the teaching positions in question are one of the few unlimited positions without *Habilitation* (or an equivalent) and thus there is much more competition.

Comment: @MaartenBuis Yes the German system is super weird that way. We have no "Akademischer Mittelbau" (people who work in science and education but are neither (phd) students nor full professors) to speak of. The union for people working in education has a campaign to improve the situation - you can read it here if you can read German: https://www.gew.de/wissenschaft/templiner-manifest/templiner-manifest-text/

Comment: @Wrzlprmft And how many in math and physics...? You're not comparing what comparable (and also not pinging me so I didn't see your answer).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: *And how many in math and physics...?* – I don’t know, but I stated that “[t]hat’s for all fields”. But, to get an estimate: The university I am most familiar with has at least fifty professors and other people with *Habilitiation* in those fields, but not a single *Lehrkraft für besondere Aufgaben.*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Whereas the number 12/year quoted at the beginning was only for math and physics.

Comment: In my field (sociology) you definitely do not want to base a career on Lehrkraft für besondere Aufgabe. They are extremely badly paid, and there is no job security. An extremely rare option would be Hochschuldozent. Though these positions are even rarer and you would still have to compete with people with a PhD.

Comment: If you have work experience outside academia you have a chance at a Fachhochschule.